# Git svn subtree workflow

Tags: git-svn, git-subtree, git-workflow

I have **project A**, which includes a **local fork of project B**.
This is, project B's potentially modified sources are included in a subtree of project A.
Project A uses svn, project B uses git.

Using git for my local copy of project A, I want to:

- Be able to **merge project B's upstream changes** into project A.
- Be able to **contribute back to project B some (not all) of the modifications** to project B's fork included in project A.
- Do it in such a way that **clean individual commits** (not squashed) are sent both to project A (via git-svn) and to project B (via git).

I've been trying hard to find a solution mixing git-svn and git-subtree capabilities (git-submodule is out of question as I want a unique source tree). But I can't find a perfect solution.

Comment: If I understand correct, your local copy of A is git-svn and has project B as subtree?
I'm currently using this setup. The only thing that does not work is that your upstream svn project A contains the individual commits of project B. If you merge the subtree to your local A and afterwards dcommit it to svn the commits of the merge are squashed into one single commit.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  
Project A's main repo is svn.  
Project B's main repo is git.  
I've got a git-svn local repo for project A.  
Then I add a local copy of project B as a subtree in my local git-svn repo for A.

Comment: And I would like to be able to send back clean commits to both projects A and B.